# Is it feasible to write if-else statement in slicc transition code blocks?

Tags: caching, gem5

Recently, I started to learn SLICC in gem5(https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part3/directory/). Currently, my task is converting Murphy language to SLICC language. But during the conversion, I found that there are some if-else statements in Murphy language, such as

```
if (cle.acksExpected=cle.acksReceived) then 
    cle.State := cache_M;
    cle.Perm := store; 
else 
    cle.State := cache_I_store_GetM_Ack_AD;
    cle.Perm := none;
endif;
```

But in the SLICC documents, the transitions code blocks seems do not cover this case.
I wonder if it works? such as

```
tansition(State1, Event, State2){
    if (expectedAcks == receivedAcks){
        do something
    }else{
         do something
    }
}
```

If I do so, should I change the related parts like action code blocks and basic configurations?